# Django model to automatically update username and date/time when Article modified

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have a model called Post and I am trying to automatically save the username of the logged in user who last modified the article along with the timestamp. So far DateTime timestamp is updating values but I am unable to achieve the same result with the username.

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    article = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
    username = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='usernames')
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
class PostForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):    

        super(PostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py**

```
class PostUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
    
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.username = request.user
        obj.save()
```

Comment: Can you add the views where you want it to be updated ?

Comment: You can not automatically achieve this, since models are normally model-unaware. There is some middleware to do this, but that is still likely not a good idea. You can make a simple mixin, and use that mixin in the `UpdateView`s and `CreateView`s where you create/update the `Post` objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `CreateView` or `UpdateView` has no `save_model` method. You use a `form_valid` method for that:

```
class PostUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.username = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

You can define the logic in a mixin, and then use this mixin in multiple views, for example:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class PostAutorMixin(LoginRequiredMixin):
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.username = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

and then use this with:

```
class PostCreate(PostAuthorMixin, CreateView):
    # …

class PostUpdate(PostAuthorMixin, UpdateView):
    # …
```

in the `PostCreate` and `PostUpdate` views you do not override the `form_valid` method.

---

> **Note**: A `ForeignKey` does *not* store the string representation (or name) of the
> referenced object in the column, it stores the primary key of the record it
> references in a column with an  `_id` suffix to a `ForeignKey` field. Therefore
> `ForeignKey`s usually do *not* end with a `_name` suffix. You might want to
> consider renaming the <s>`username`</s> field to `author`.

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a class-based view to authenticated users with the
> [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** mixin [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin).

Answer (score 2):

first if you want your username just set by request.user then add editable=False to your username field in Post model.

```
username = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='usernames', editable=False)
```

then in your **admin.py**:

```
from . import models
from django.contrib import admin

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.username = request.user
        obj.save()

admin.site.register(models.Post, PostAdmin)
```

***Edite Starts from here***

*models.py*

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms

class Post(models.Model):
    article = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
    username = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='usernames') # we don't need editable=False anymore
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
```

*views.py*

```
from . import models
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib import messages

def post(request, id):
    post = get_object_or_404(models.Post, id=id) # get a specific post with id
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = models.PostForm(request.POST, instance=post) # create a post form instance
        if form.is_valid():
            data = models.Post() # create a post model instance
            data.article = form.cleaned_data['article']
            data.username = request.user
            # updated_at field updating automatically
            data.save() # dont't forget to save these data
            messages.success(request, 'Article updated successfully') # this line is optional
        else:
            messages.success(request, form.errors) # this line is optional
    else:
       form = models.PostForm(instance=post)
    return render(request, 'post.html', {'form': form})
```

*urls.py*

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'post'
urlpatterns = [
    path('post/<int:id>', views.post, name='article'),
]
```

*html (template)* without widget tweaks (simple form)

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

*html (template)* with widget tweaks and bootstrap classes (optional)

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}

<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-control-border"></div>
        {{ field.label }}
        {% render_field field class="form-control" %}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary-2">Send</button>
</form>
```

> let me know if there is a Error

Comment: it did not work and it did not give me any errors.

Comment: admin works fine. let's do this in template. first tell me what kind of form your using or what kind of form you wish to use? django form or html form? and please add your views.py and html codes to the question

Comment: added the additional code of views and form

Comment: Willem Van Onsem answered well with CBV. actually i don't know much about CBV but i can do it with FBV. tell me if you want FBV

Comment: Yes please show me how to also achieve this with FBV.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `request.user`

```
# Editing Article View
post_to_be_modified.username = request.user
post_to_be_modified.save()
```

Although the field should be called `user` or `author` as it is not just storing a username, it is storing a user.

You can't automatically do this as a user isn't a global Python object, which means it has to be modified through a view parameter.